# Is it possible to execute multiple beeline commands from python using subprocess and capture the output of each query

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, subprocess, beeline

How can I execute multiple beeline commands from python using subprocess and capture the output of each query?
I am able to execute the below code in sequence but it is not running in parallel. Also, if the first command fails for some reason the second one is not getting executed. I would like to run the same query on multiple servers simultaneously and capture the output. Any help on this?

```
import subprocess
url = ['host1','host2','host3','host4',...'host10'] 

child_processes = []
for i in url:
    jdbc_string ="jdbc:hive2://" + i + ":1000/;ssl=true"
    beeline_cmd = ['beeline','-u',jdbc_string,'-n',userid,'-p',password,'-e','"select count(*) from DB.TABLENAME;"']
    p = subprocess.Popen(beeline_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    child_processes.append(p) 
 
for j in child_processes:
    j.wait()  
for j in child_processes:
    j.communicate()
```

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be done in parallel instead of sequentially you might want to look at threads. Without multi-threading, I would assume you are stuck doing it procedurally.

[This page may help.](https://www.toptal.com/python/beginners-guide-to-concurrency-and-parallelism-in-python)